# Cannot run a shell script created on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell

I seem to be having a weird problem, the solution for which might be dead simple and I am just being blind.

My development environment is Windows.  I create a deployment archive file, within which contains a shell script file (called install.sh).  I sftp this archive over to a linux environment, untar it and try to run execute the script (after chmod to make it executable) and I get this error:

syntax error: unexpected end of file

I don't notice any errors in the file.  I delete this file, create a new install.sh, copy over the exact contents from my Windows env, chmod it again, run it again and this time it runs fine!

I have no idea why it does not run the first time I untar it.  Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your file:

```
cat --show-nonprinting file
```

Remove carriage returns from Windows/DOS:

```
tr -d "\r" < file > fixed_file
```

Comment: Looks like it was carriage returns that was causing it.  However I couldn't use the tr, I used this instead:      sed -i -e 's/\r//g' install.sh

Answer (score 2):

Linux and Windows uses different end of line (CL or CLRF), or maybe it's an encoding problem. You should check the differences between the running sh and the non-running one.